# Teamcity not picking up fastlane MATCH_PASSWORD environment variable

Tags: teamcity, fastlane, fastlane-match

So i have a build configuration which has been configured with the build steps of command line. Within this I have set a environment parameter **MATCH_PASSWORD** and the value is the correct password which was generated and stored as a access key in bitbucket.

Since the key already exists locally on my machine when i run the command to execute the lane within the fast lane file. There are no errors. But when i push my branch and TeamCity is compiling once it executes the lane and tries to clone the repo the following error message is being outputted and looped into the log.

```
[10:09:43][Step 1/1] [10:09:43]: Cloning remote git repo...
[10:09:43][Step 1/1] [10:09:43]: If cloning the repo takes too long, you can use the `clone_branch_directly` option in match.
[10:09:46][Step 1/1] [10:09:45]: Neither the MATCH_PASSWORD environment variable nor the local keychain contained a password.
[10:09:46][Step 1/1] [10:09:45]: Bailing out instead of asking for a password, since this is non-interactive mode.
[10:09:46][Step 1/1] [10:09:45]: Couldn't decrypt the repo, please make sure you enter the right password!
[10:09:46][Step 1/1] security: SecKeychainSearchCopyNext: The specified item could not be found in the keychain.
```

I'm kind of baffled since I've set the environment variable in teamcity, it should recognise it, pick it up and set it on the agent.

Answer (score 2):

In your `Fastfile`, you can use `puts ENV["MATCH_PASSWORD"]` before calling `match` to see if the password is actually configured correctly. If it is but it still isn't picked up correctly by match for some reason, please [find us on github](https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane) and follow the instructions there to file an issue.